# Media query not working when styling ninja form in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, ninja-forms

newbie on here so apologies if I get anything wrong on here.

I'm building a wordpress website for a client and trying to style the contact form (currently using the Ninja form plugin). With the basic version, it is easy to have two fields in one row, but what I want to do is for mobile view, make the right hand field file neatly underneath into one column.

The relevant CSS in the plug-in is below:

```
.nf-form-cont {
.five-sixths,
.four-sixths,
.one-fourth,
.one-half,
.one-sixth,
.one-third,
.three-fourths,
.three-sixths,
.two-fourths,
.two-sixths,
.two-thirds {
    clear: initial;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;
    .inside {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    &::after {
        clear: both;
        content: "";
        display: block;
    }
}

.one-half,
.three-sixths,
.two-fourths {
    width: 48.717948717948715%;
}
```

I've written the CSS below which makes the second field drop below the first and removes the margin:

```
.one-half {
    margin-left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This works fine, until I place in a media query like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 719px) {

.one-half {
    margin-left:0;
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```

From reading other questions on here, I believe the issue might be something to do with needing an ID in the media query also, but I've tried numerous IDs without success. When I use Inspect on Google to check the code, the media query doesn't even seem to exist.

Hope someone can shed some light on this! Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup as well?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter there's a load of JavaScript (which unfortunately I've not learned to code yet) - is that what you would need?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
.one-half {
    margin:0;
    width: 48%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Hi P Sebastian - that doesn't really solve the problem unfortunately - the issue is the code not working when placed in the media query. I think it's something to do with not having an ID, but I could be wrong!

Comment: try example : @media screen and (min-width : 320px)

Comment: @P Sebastian same issue - using the media query just overrides the css

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the bottom of your appearance->Additional Css

```
    @media screen and (max-width : 680px){
     .one-fourth {
           min-width: 100%;
           display:block;
        }
    }
```